# cp command force

Tags: linux, cp

currently there's a xxx dir already in /home/yyy
 I'm trying to overwrite it
cp -fr ../xxx /home/yyy/
doesn't work still prompts me to overwrite the individual files. how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, see if it's aliased. You can do this by typing `alias cp`. If it's in that list you can remove it by typing unalias. (The default) -i option will be gone too.

Overwriting won't be a problem anymore...

Answer (score 3):

or, to circumvent the problem with aliases in the first place, call the `cp` binary directly. Mostly, this will work:

```
/bin/cp -fr .../xxx /home/yyy/
```

Comment: Or escape the command `\cp -fr ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are using BASH or SH as your shell, in which case you can explicitly undo all aliases by prefixing your command line with `command`. E.g.

```
command cp -fr ../xxx /home/yyy/
```

Which would ignore any aliases for `cp` *and* any shell-function called `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://www.saiweb.co.uk/linux/cp-f-prompting)

> -i is ‘interactive’ aka ALWAYS PROMPT, and evidently overrides -f

Make sure your cp is not aliased or something. (run `type cp` ).
As a simple example, the order of the options is important. For instance
`rm -if f` will say nothing. `rm -fi f` will prompt me before removing f.

Comment: if it's aliased, AFAIK his input should override the alias, because it will be something like `cp -i -fr` etc.

Comment: @Lo'oris:  On my system (RHEL 5), the -i overrides the -f.